# Can I repair my helicopter ?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I tend to clip buildings and trees when flying low.  Can I  repair my helicopter when it gets damaged?  If so, where ? (I haven't bought my own helicopter yet, but I have bought the helipad ). (Single player)

Can I repair it when in Online play?

Comment: When on Multiplayer, you cannot repair it. Once it gets destroyed you need to contact Pegasus for a replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just switch between characters and your vehicle regardless if it's plane, car, boat or helicopter, once you switch back it will be in mint condition.